# return all possible values with which.max in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

I have the following dataset

```
clust       T2       n
1            a       1
1            b       3
1            c       3
2            d       5
3            a       4 
3            b       3
4            b       5
4            c       8
4            t       6
4            e       7
etc..
```

using the following function:

```
library(dplyr)
table <- data %>% group_by(clust) %>% summarise(max = max(n), name1 = T2[which.max(n)])
```

I get this output

```
clust   max  name1
1        3    b
2        5    d
3        4    a
4        8    c
etc
```

however there are cases where there are two or more T2 values corresponding to max(n). how can I record those value too?

i.e.

```
clust   max  name1
1        3    b,c
2        5    d
3        4    a
4        8    c
etc
```

or

```
clust   max  name1
1        3    b
1        3    c
2        5    d
3        4    a
4        8    c
etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a `==` instead of `which.max` (that returns only the first index of `max` value) and `paste` together with `toString`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
    group_by(clust) %>% 
    summarise(max = max(n), name1 = toString(T2[n == max(n)]))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  clust   max name1
#  <int> <int> <chr>
#1     1     3 b, c 
#2     2     5 d    
#3     3     4 a    
#4     4     8 c
```

and this can be expanded with `separate_rows` in the next step

```
data %>%
    group_by(clust) %>% 
    summarise(max = max(n), name1 = toString(T2[n == max(n)])) %>%
    separate_rows(name1, sep=",\\s+")
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  clust   max name1
#  <int> <int> <chr>
#1     1     3 b    
#2     1     3 c    
#3     2     5 d    
#4     3     4 a    
#5     4     8 c
```

Or have a `list` column and then `unnest`

```
data %>%
    group_by(clust) %>% 
    summarise(max = max(n), name1 = list(T2[n == max(n)]))  %>%
    unnest(c(name1))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  clust   max name1
#  <int> <int> <chr>
#1     1     3 b    
#2     1     3 c    
#3     2     5 d    
#4     3     4 a    
#5     4     8 c
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(clust = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), T2 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "b", "c", "t", "e"), 
    n = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 7L)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```